# React Native not detecting Android emulator

Tags: android, react-native

When I do react-native run-android I get this error:

```
info Running jetifier to migrate libraries to AndroidX. You can disable it using "--no-jetifier" flag.
Jetifier found 960 file(s) to forward-jetify. Using 6 workers...
info Starting JS server...
/bin/sh: 1: adb: not found
info Launching emulator...
error Failed to launch emulator. Reason: No emulators found as an output of `emulator -list-avds`.
warn Please launch an emulator manually or connect a device. Otherwise app may fail to launch.
info Installing the app...

Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 7.0.
Use '--warning-mode all' to show the individual deprecation warnings.
See https://docs.gradle.org/6.0.1/userguide/command_line_interface.html#sec:command_line_warnings

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Task 'installDebug' not found in project ':app'.

* Try:
Run gradlew tasks to get a list of available tasks. Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 4s

error Failed to install the app. Make sure you have the Android development environment set up: https://reactnative.dev/docs/environment-setup. Run CLI with --verbose flag for more details.
Error: Command failed: ./gradlew app:installDebug -PreactNativeDevServerPort=8081

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Task 'installDebug' not found in project ':app'.

* Try:
Run gradlew tasks to get a list of available tasks. Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org
```

I dont get it, before I run my React Native app I open the Android emulator first. I also noticed that my android studio doesn't have 'configure' on welcome page, so I have to start a project if I want to acces the sdk manager and avd manager.

Comment: i faced the same issue, using **React native .62**  
try running the following 
`react-native run-android --variant PreDebug`

Comment: I get the same error

Comment: i think you need to check your project Gradle, open your project platform from android studio then try sync and update Gradle and rebuild the project

Comment: try to run `npx react-native run-android` command

Comment: I still get the same error

Comment: Does all of your environment setups is correct?...According to this https://reactnative.dev/docs/environment-setup

Comment: Is expo required? Because I only installed react native cli.

Comment: try this  ``cd android && ./gradlew clean``

Comment: @KevinBryan, no expo is not required, go to that above page and select the `React Native CLI Quickstart` option which is residing beside `expo CLI Quickstart` and check all the environment setup.

Answer (score 0):

Try in the same terminal that you put `npx react-native run-android` , set environment variables again like :

> source $HOME/.zprofile (if you use zsh)

> source $HOME/.bash_profile (if you use bash)